# Genuino 101 - sending a csv string to Android over BLE

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Genuino 101 board and I want it to speak with Android via Bluetooth Low Energy [BLE]. Values are continously updating and the goal is sending a comma-separated string of `signed int`s, e.g. -10,2,1023 which is put together in this way:

```
void loop() {
  float first, second, third;

  if (central) 
  {
    Serial.print("Connected to central: ");
    [...]
    // as long as the central is still connected:
    while (central.connected()) 
    {
    [...]
    String truple = String((int)first)+","+String((int)second)+","+String((int)third);

    // now from here I want to send this string to the Android UI: how to?
  }
```

I know each message has to stay below the 20 bytes. For this board there is a library taking care of BLE, CurieBLE.h but taking a look to the documentation I couldn't figure out what's the best approach to achieve the target. I just need to send these values to Android, no need to receive data

Thanks a lot in advance to those who will try to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practical solution to accomplish my goal came from the wonderful [pfodApp website](http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/BLE/index.html#Arduino101). The code can be found [here](http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/BLE/SampleScreensArduino101.ino.txt) and - since it makes use of the Genuino 101 libraries [e.g. `CurieBLE.h`] and the [nRF UART service](https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/adding-app-support) - it is absolutely the best solution for this particular target

```
/*
    Sample Pfod Screens for Arduino/Genuino 101 BLE Board
    using pfodApp V2 menus
*/
// Using Arduino/Genunio 101 BLE Board
// Use Arduino V1.6.8 IDE
// using Intel Curie Board library V1.0.7
/*
 * (c)2014-2017 Forward Computing and Control Pty. Ltd.
 * NSW Australia, www.forward.com.au
 * This code is not warranted to be fit for any purpose. You may only use it at your own risk.
 * This code may be freely used for both private and commercial use
 * Provide this copyright is maintained.
 */

#define DEBUG
#include "CurieIMU.h"
#include <CurieBLE.h>
// download the libraries from http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/pfodParserLibraries/index.html
// pfodParser V3.8+, pfodDwgControls V1.2+
#include <pfodParser.h>
#include <pfodDwgControls.h>
int swap01(int); // method prototype for slider end swaps

// =========== pfodBLESerial definitions
const char* localName = "101 BLE";  // <<<<<<  change this string to customize the adverised name of your board (max 8 chars)
class pfodBLESerial : public BLEPeripheral, public Stream {
  public:
    pfodBLESerial(); void begin(); void poll(); size_t write(uint8_t); size_t write(const uint8_t*, size_t); int read();
    int available(); void flush(); int peek(); void close(); bool isConnected();
  private:
    const static uint8_t pfodEOF[1]; const static char* pfodCloseConnection;  static const int BLE_MAX_LENGTH = 20;
    static const int BLE_RX_MAX_LENGTH = 256; static volatile size_t rxHead; static volatile size_t rxTail;
    volatile static uint8_t rxBuffer[BLE_RX_MAX_LENGTH];  volatile static bool connected;
    size_t txIdx;  uint8_t txBuffer[BLE_MAX_LENGTH]; static void connectHandler(BLECentral& central);
    static void disconnectHandler(BLECentral& central); static void receiveHandler(BLECentral& central, BLECharacteristic& rxCharacteristic);
    static void addReceiveBytes(const uint8_t* bytes, size_t len); BLEService uartService = BLEService("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
    BLEDescriptor uartNameDescriptor = BLEDescriptor("2901", localName);
    BLECharacteristic rxCharacteristic = BLECharacteristic("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E", BLEWrite, BLE_MAX_LENGTH);
    BLEDescriptor rxNameDescriptor = BLEDescriptor("2901", "RX - (Write)");
    BLECharacteristic txCharacteristic = BLECharacteristic("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E", BLEIndicate, BLE_MAX_LENGTH);
    BLEDescriptor txNameDescriptor = BLEDescriptor("2901", "TX - (Indicate)");
};
volatile size_t pfodBLESerial::rxHead = 0; volatile size_t pfodBLESerial::rxTail = 0;
volatile uint8_t pfodBLESerial::rxBuffer[BLE_RX_MAX_LENGTH]; const uint8_t pfodBLESerial::pfodEOF[1] = {(uint8_t) - 1};
const char* pfodBLESerial::pfodCloseConnection = "{!}"; volatile bool pfodBLESerial::connected = false;
// =========== end pfodBLESerial definitions

pfodParser parser("101v10"); // create a parser to handle the pfod messages
pfodDwgs dwgs(&parser);  // drawing support
pfodBLESerial bleSerial; // create a BLE serial connection

const int LED_pin = LED_BUILTIN;

Gauge gauge(&dwgs);
Slider slider('a', &dwgs);

const int maxTextChars = 11;
byte currentText[maxTextChars + 1]  = "Hello"; // allow max 11 chars + null == 12, note  msg {'x`11~Example Text Input screen.\n"  enforces max 11 bytes in return value

const int imagesize = 50;  // this set the image size
bool sendCleanImage = false; // this is set when next image load/update should send blank image

int currentSingleSelection = 1;

const int MAX_MULTI_SELECTIONS = 5; //max 5 possible selections out of all possible,
long multiSelections[MAX_MULTI_SELECTIONS]; // -1 means not selected

int ax, ay, az; // acceleration divided by 16,  1024 ~ 1G
int axRaw, ayRaw, azRaw;         // raw accelerometer values

int redValue = 127;
int greenValue = 127;
int blueValue = 127;
int fanPosition = 0;
const unsigned long RAW_DATA_INTERVAL = 2000; // 2 sec
unsigned long rawDataTimer;
int counter = 0;

// the setup routine runs once on reset:
void setup() {
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.begin(115200);
#endif
  for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
    // wait a few secs to see if we are being programmed
    delay(1000);
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(' ');
#endif
  }
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.println();
#endif
  // initialize device
  Serial.println("Initializing IMU device...");
  CurieIMU.begin();

  // Set the accelerometer range to 2G
  CurieIMU.setAccelerometerRange(2);

  // set advertised local name and service UUID
  // begin initialization
  bleSerial.begin();
  parser.connect(&bleSerial);

  // <<<<<<<<< Your extra setup code goes here
  // setup multiselections
  // just clear for now
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MULTI_SELECTIONS; i++) {
    multiSelections[i] = -1; // empty
  }
  rawDataTimer = millis();

  gauge.setLabel(F("LED\n"));
  slider.setLabel(F("PWM "));
  slider.setValue(0); // 0 to 255
  gauge.setValue(slider.getValue());

  pinMode(LED_pin, OUTPUT);

}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  byte cmd = parser.parse(); // parse incoming data from connection
  // parser returns non-zero when a pfod command is fully parsed
  if (cmd != 0) {  // have parsed a complete msg { to }
    byte* pfodFirstArg = parser.getFirstArg(); // may point to \0 if no arguments in this msg.
    long pfodLongRtn; // used for parsing long return arguments, if any
    if ('.' == cmd) {
      // pfodApp has connected and sent {.} , it is asking for the main menu
      // send back the menu designed
      if (!parser.isRefresh()) {
        sendMainMenu();
      } else {
        sendMainMenuUpdate();
      }
    } else if ('p' == cmd) {
      sendPlottingScreen(); // plots the raw data being logged
    } else if ('l' == cmd) {
      if (!parser.isRefresh()) {
        sendListMenu();
      } else {
        sendListMenuUpdate();
      }
    } else if ('s' == cmd) {
      if (!parser.isRefresh()) {
        sendSliderMenu();
      } else {
        sendSliderMenuUpdate();
      }
    } else  if ('x' == cmd) {
      // return from text input,  pickup the first arg which is the number
      strncpy((char*)currentText, (const char*)pfodFirstArg, sizeof(currentText) - 1); // keep null at end
      parser.print(F("{}")); // nothing to update pfodApp will request previous menu
    } else  if ('y' == cmd) {
      sendSingleSelectionScreen();
    } else  if ('S' == cmd) {
      // return from single selection input, pickup the first arg which is the number
      parser.parseLong(pfodFirstArg, &pfodLongRtn); // stores result in a long
      currentSingleSelection = (int)pfodLongRtn;
      parser.print(F("{}"));
    } else  if ('F' == cmd) {
      if (!parser.isRefresh()) {
        sendFanControl();
      } else {
        sendFanControlUpdate();
      }
    } else if ('G' == cmd) {
      if (!parser.isRefresh()) {
        dwgMenu();
      } else {
        dwgMenuUpdate();
      }
    } else if ('A' == cmd) { // user pressed menu item that loaded drawing with load cmd 'z'
      byte dwgCmd = parser.parseDwgCmd();  // parse rest of dwgCmd, return first char of active cmd
      if (slider.getCmd() == dwgCmd) { // user touched LED control
        int col = parser.getTouchedCol();
        slider.setValue(col); // set new value
        gauge.setValue(slider.getValue()); // set gauge from slider
        analogWrite(LED_pin, slider.getValue()); // set LED PWM
      }
      sendDrawingUpdates_z(); // update the drawing
      // always send back a response or pfodApp will timeout

    } else if ('z' == cmd) { // pfodApp is asking to load dwg 'z'
      if (!parser.isRefresh()) { // not refresh send whole dwg
        sendDrawing_z();
      } else { // refresh just update drawing state
        sendDrawingUpdates_z();
      }

    } else  if ('o' == cmd) {
      // return from fan control, pickup the first arg which is the number
      parser.parseLong(pfodFirstArg, &pfodLongRtn);
      fanPosition = (int)pfodLongRtn;
      sendFanControlUpdate();
    } else  if ('r' == cmd) {
      // return from red colour selector, pickup the first arg which is the number
      parser.parseLong(pfodFirstArg, &pfodLongRtn);
      redValue = (int)pfodLongRtn;
      sendColourSelectorUpdate();
    } else  if ('g' == cmd) {
      // return from green colour selector, pickup the first arg which is the number
      parser.parseLong(pfodFirstArg, &pfodLongRtn);
      greenValue = (int)pfodLongRtn;
      sendColourSelectorUpdate();
    } else  if ('b' == cmd) {
      // return from blue colour selector, pickup the first arg which is the number
      parser.parseLong(pfodFirstArg, &pfodLongRtn);
      blueValue = (int)pfodLongRtn;
      sendColourSelectorUpdate();
    } else  if ('m' == cmd) {
      sendMultiSelectionScreen();
    } else  if ('M' == cmd) {
      // return from multi selection input
      byte* argIdx = pfodFirstArg; // pickup the first arg which is the number
      // will be null if no arges
      int i = 0;
      for (; (i < MAX_MULTI_SELECTIONS) && (*argIdx != 0); i++) {
        argIdx = parser.parseLong(argIdx, &multiSelections[i]);
        //argIdx will be null after last arg is parsed
      }
      if (i < MAX_MULTI_SELECTIONS) {
        // add a -1 to terminate the array of indices
        multiSelections[i] = -1;
      }
      parser.print(F("{}"));
    } else  if ('L' == cmd) {
      if (!parser.isRefresh()) {
        sendColourSelector();
      } else {
        sendColourSelectorUpdate();
      }
    } else  if ('i' == cmd) {
      sendTextInputScreen();
    } else  if ('u' == cmd) {
      sendRawDataScreen();
    } else if ('!' == cmd) {
      // CloseConnection command
      closeConnection(parser.getPfodAppStream());
    } else {
      // unknown command
      parser.print(F("{}")); // always send back a pfod msg otherwise pfodApp will disconnect.
    }
  }

  // this section will send raw data at set intervals, in CSV format
  if (millis() - rawDataTimer > RAW_DATA_INTERVAL) { // send raw data
    rawDataTimer = millis(); // allow it to drift due to delays in sending data

    // read raw accelerometer measurements from device
    CurieIMU.readAccelerometer(axRaw, ayRaw, azRaw);

    // since we are using 2G range
    // -2g maps to a raw value of -32768
    // +2g maps to a raw value of 32767

    ax = axRaw >> 4;  // divide by 16 to make 1G about 1024 counts
    ay = ayRaw >> 4;  // divide by 16 to make 1G about 1024 counts
    az = azRaw >> 4;  // divide by 16 to make 1G about 1024 counts

    int sec = rawDataTimer / 1000;
    int remainder = rawDataTimer - (sec * 1000);
    int tenths = remainder / 100;
    parser.print(sec); // the time in seconds, first field
    parser.print('.');
    parser.print(tenths);
    parser.print(','); // field separator
    parser.print(ax); // second field
    parser.print(','); // field separator
    parser.print(ay); // third field
    parser.print(','); // field separator
    parser.print(az); // fourth field
    parser.println(); // terminate data record
  }

}

void closeConnection(Stream *io) {
  // add any special code here to force connection to be dropped
  ((pfodBLESerial*)io)->close();
}
void sendMainMenu() {
  // put main msg in input array
  parser.print(F("{,~101 Sample Screens"));
  parser.sendVersion(); // send pfod menu version
  parser.print(F("|^l~Lists|^s~Sliders and Dwgs|^i~Text Input|^u~Raw Data|^p~Plots}"));
}
void sendMainMenuUpdate() {
  parser.print(F("{;}")); // nothing to update here
}

void sendSliderMenu() {
  parser.print(F("{,~Slider and Dwg Examples"));
  parser.sendVersion(); // send pfod menu version
  parser.print(F("|L<bg w>~<+1><r>Colour</r> <g>Selector</g> <bl>Example</bl>"
                 "|F~<+1>Fan Control"
                 "|G~<+1>Drawings\nSlider/Gauge Example"
                 "}"));
}

void sendSliderMenuUpdate() {
  parser.print(F("{;}")); // nothing to update here
}

void sendListMenu() {
  parser.print(F("{,~Lists"));
  parser.sendVersion(); // send pfod menu version
  parser.print(F("|y~Single Selection|m~Multi-selection}"));
}
void sendListMenuUpdate() {
  parser.print(F("{;}")); // nothing to update here
}

void sendTextInputScreen() {
  parser.print(F("{'x`"));
  parser.print(maxTextChars);
  parser.print(F("~Text Input\n(Limited to 11 chars by Arduino code to match allocated storage)"
                 "|"));
  parser.print((char*)currentText);
  parser.print(F("}"));

}

void sendSingleSelectionScreen() {
  parser.print(F("{?S`")); // rest of msg handle in main loop
  parser.print(currentSingleSelection);
  parser.print(F("~Single Selection"
                 "|Enable|Disable}"));
}

void sendMultiSelectionScreen() {
  parser.print(F("{*M"));
  // add the current selections
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MULTI_SELECTIONS; i++) {
    long idx = multiSelections[i];
    if (idx < 0) {
      break;
    } // else
    parser.print(F("`"));
    parser.print(idx);
  }
  parser.print(F("~Multi-selection"
                 "|Fade on/off|3 Levels|Feature A|Feature B|Feature C}"));
}

void sendColourSelector() {
  parser.print(F("{,"));
  sendColourScreen();
  parser.print(F("}"));
}
void sendColourSelectorUpdate() {
  parser.print(F("{;"));
  parser.print(F("<bg "));  // sent the background colour in the prompt area to match the slider settings
  if (redValue < 16) {
    parser.print('0');
  }
  parser.print(redValue, HEX);
  if (greenValue < 16) {
    parser.print('0');
  }
  parser.print(greenValue, HEX);
  if (blueValue < 16) {
    parser.print('0');
  }
  parser.print(blueValue, HEX);
  parser.print(F(">"));
  parser.print(F("|r"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(redValue);
  parser.print(F("|g"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(greenValue);
  parser.print(F("|b"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(blueValue);

  parser.print(F("}"));
}

void sendColourScreen() {
  parser.print(F("<bg "));  // sent the background colour in the prompt area to match the slider settings
  if (redValue < 16) {
    parser.print('0');
  }
  parser.print(redValue, HEX);
  if (greenValue < 16) {
    parser.print('0');
  }
  parser.print(greenValue, HEX);
  if (blueValue < 16) {
    parser.print('0');
  }
  parser.print(blueValue, HEX);
  parser.print(F(">~"));
  parser.sendVersion(); // send pfod menu version
  parser.print(F("|r<bg r>"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(redValue);
  parser.print(F("~<w>Red <b>"));
  parser.print(F("`255`0~</b>")); //
  parser.print(F("|g<bg g>"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(greenValue);
  parser.print(F("~<bk>Green <b>"));
  parser.print(F("`255`0~</b>")); //
  parser.print(F("|b<bg bl>"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(blueValue);
  parser.print(F("~<w>Blue <b>"));
  parser.print(F("`255`0~</b>")); //
}

void sendFanControl() {
  parser.print(F("{,"));
  sendFanControlScreen();
  parser.print(F("}"));
}
void sendFanControlUpdate() {
  parser.print(F("{;"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(fanPosition);
  parser.print(F("}"));
}

void sendFanControlScreen() {
  parser.print(F("~<+5>Fan Control"));
  parser.sendVersion(); // send pfod menu version
  parser.print(F("|o"));
  parser.print('`');
  parser.print(fanPosition);
  parser.print(F("~<+4><b>Fan is "));
  parser.print(F("~~Off\\Low\\High"));
}

void dwgMenu() {
  parser.print(F("{,"));  // start a Menu screen pfod message
  // send menu background, format, prompt, refresh and version
  parser.print(F("~`0"));
  parser.sendVersion(); // send the menu version
  // send menu items
  parser.print(F("|+A~z"));
  parser.print(F("}"));  // close pfod message
}

void dwgMenuUpdate() {
  parser.print(F("{;"));  // start an Update Menu pfod message
  // send menu items
  parser.print(F("|A"));
  parser.print(F("}"));  // close pfod message
}

void sendDrawing_z() {
  dwgs.start(50, 35, dwgs.WHITE); // background defaults to WHITE if omitted i.e. dwgs.start(50,35);
  parser.sendVersion(); // send the parser version to cache this image
  dwgs.pushZero(25, 12, 1.5); // move zero to centre of dwg to 25,12 and scale by 1.5 times
  gauge.draw(); // draw the control
  dwgs.popZero();
  dwgs.pushZero(9, 29); // move zero to centre of dwg to 9,30 and scale is 1 (default)
  slider.draw(); // draw the control
  dwgs.popZero();
  dwgs.end();
}

void sendDrawingUpdates_z() {
  dwgs.startUpdate();
  gauge.update(); // update with current state
  slider.update(); // update with current state
  dwgs.end();
}


void sendRawDataScreen() {
  // this illustrates how you can send much more then 255 bytes as raw data.
  // The {=Raw Data Screen} just tells the pfodApp to open the rawData screen and give it a title
  // all the rest of the text (outside the { } ) is just raw data text and can be a much as you like
  // Note the raw data includes { } using { is OK as long as the next char is not a pfodApp msg identifer
  // that is the following cannot appear in rawData {@ {. {: {^ {= {' {# {?  or {*
  parser.print(F("{=Raw Data Screen}"
                 "This is the Raw Data Screen\n\n"
                 "The pfodDevice can write more the 255 chars to this screen.\n"
                 "Any bytes sent outside the pfod message { } start/end characters are"
                 " displayed here.\n"
                 " The raw data used for plotting and data logging is also displayed here.\n"
                 "\nUse the Back Button on the mobile to go back to the previous menu."
                 "\n \n"));
}

void sendPlottingScreen() {
  parser.print(F("{=" // streaming raw data screen
                 "Accel x,y,z versus time (1024 is approx 1G)" // plot title
                 "|Time (sec)|aX~1200~-1200|aY~1200~-1200|gZ~1200~-1200}")); // show data in a plot
  // these match the 3 fields in the raw data record
}
// ========== pfodBLESerial methods
pfodBLESerial::pfodBLESerial() : BLEPeripheral() {
  setLocalName(localName);  addAttribute(uartService);  addAttribute(uartNameDescriptor);  setAdvertisedServiceUuid(uartService.uuid());
  addAttribute(rxCharacteristic);  addAttribute(rxNameDescriptor);  rxCharacteristic.setEventHandler(BLEWritten, pfodBLESerial::receiveHandler);
  setEventHandler(BLEConnected, pfodBLESerial::connectHandler);  setEventHandler(BLEDisconnected, pfodBLESerial::disconnectHandler);
  addAttribute(txCharacteristic);  addAttribute(txNameDescriptor);
};

bool pfodBLESerial::isConnected() {
  return (connected && txCharacteristic.subscribed());
}
void pfodBLESerial::begin() {
  BLEPeripheral::begin();
}

void pfodBLESerial::close() {
  BLEPeripheral::disconnect();
}

void pfodBLESerial::poll() {
  BLEPeripheral::poll();
}

size_t pfodBLESerial::write(const uint8_t* bytes, size_t len) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    write(bytes[i]);
  }
  return len; // just assume it is all written
}

size_t pfodBLESerial::write(uint8_t b) {
  BLEPeripheral::poll();
  if (!isConnected()) {
    return 1;
  }
  txBuffer[txIdx++] = b;
  if ((txIdx == sizeof(txBuffer)) || (b == ((uint8_t)'\n')) || (b == ((uint8_t)'}')) ) {
    flush(); // send this buffer if full or end of msg or rawdata newline
  }
  return 1;
}

int pfodBLESerial::read() {
  if (rxTail == rxHead) {
    return -1;
  }
  // note increment rxHead befor writing
  // so need to increment rxTail befor reading
  rxTail = (rxTail + 1) % sizeof(rxBuffer);
  uint8_t b = rxBuffer[rxTail];
  return b;
}

// called as part of parser.parse() so will poll() each loop()
int pfodBLESerial::available() {
  BLEPeripheral::poll();
  flush(); // send any pending data now. This happens at the top of each loop()
  int rtn = ((rxHead + sizeof(rxBuffer)) - rxTail ) % sizeof(rxBuffer);
  return rtn;
}

void pfodBLESerial::flush() {
  if (txIdx == 0) {
    return;
  }
  txCharacteristic.setValue(txBuffer, txIdx);
  txIdx = 0;
  BLEPeripheral::poll();
}

int pfodBLESerial::peek() {
  BLEPeripheral::poll();
  if (rxTail == rxHead) {
    return -1;
  }
  size_t nextIdx = (rxTail + 1) % sizeof(rxBuffer);
  uint8_t byte = rxBuffer[nextIdx];
  return byte;
}

void pfodBLESerial::connectHandler(BLECentral& central) {
  // clear parser with -1 incase partial message left
  // should not be one
  addReceiveBytes(pfodEOF, sizeof(pfodEOF));
  connected = true;
}

void pfodBLESerial::disconnectHandler(BLECentral& central) {
  // parser.closeConnection();
  // clear parser with -1 and insert {!} incase connection just lost
  addReceiveBytes(pfodEOF, sizeof(pfodEOF));
  addReceiveBytes((const uint8_t*)pfodCloseConnection, sizeof(pfodCloseConnection));
  connected = false;
}

void pfodBLESerial::addReceiveBytes(const uint8_t* bytes, size_t len) {
  // note increment rxHead befor writing
  // so need to increment rxTail befor reading
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    rxHead = (rxHead + 1) % sizeof(rxBuffer);
    rxBuffer[rxHead] = bytes[i];
  }
}

void pfodBLESerial::receiveHandler(BLECentral& central, BLECharacteristic& rxCharacteristic) {
  size_t len = rxCharacteristic.valueLength();
  const unsigned char *data = rxCharacteristic.value();
  addReceiveBytes((const uint8_t*)data, len);
}
//======================= end pfodBLESerial methods
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

- attach ble module to genuino, use software serial libraries, because only one usart on the board and it is already for debugging in your sketch
- init ble in setup()
- send data to ble using serial.println or other routines if ble manufacturer provides firmware support

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for your kind suggestion but I found a quicker solution

PS Genuino 101 has an integrated BLE module: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoard101